# Add bottom border in multiple TD using CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

My Website Link: [**Search Page**](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/search.htm)

I have the following CSS which works if I do search by Name but not by Specialty:

```
.displayresult {
    display: block;
}
#fname, #lname, #splabel, #addlabel, #pnlabel {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
#first, #last, #specialty, #address, #phone {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

If the user picks specialty and choose an option, the CSS only adds a double border on the last TD.

How do I modify the CSS or jQuery Script to:

- Make it so that it adds border after each TD?

AND/OR

- Make one TD white and the next TD grey and the next TD white and
  the next TD grey and so forth?

I have the following jQuery, which does not work and does the same thing as CSS:

```
$("#fname").css('border-bottom-style', 'double');
```

Please visit the link above to get a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Make one TD white and the next TD gray and the next TD white and the next TD gray and so forth*

You can do this:

```
td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: gray;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRQhQ/)

Comment: That is not working, especially with my script. No matter what I do it always adds a border on the last ROW. Your DEMO works fine but my TD are created with JQuery.

Comment: Could you please post your code in the http://jsfiddle.net/. I will have a look into it.

Comment: WOW that actually works... But i think i was a little unclear. I meant the first result row should be white and the second row should be gray and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the same ID across multiple elements.  Id's are designed to be a singularity, assigned to a single element in the DOM.

The reason why your code isn't working is because you're expecting the `#fname` to function like a class.

You should be doing `<td class="fname">` instead of `<td id="#fname">`